# Legal status of "Star Division (c) 1995" fonts that came with Sun Office 5.2

Tags: fonts, font-licensing

I'm sorry if this is not the right place to ask, but I have seen other "font license" related questions on this site, and no amount of googling has yielded an answer.

Some time in 2001, I downloaded the free (archived articles say "for personal use") Sun Office 5.2, which came with a nice selection of fonts. That eventually became OpenOffice, so obviously I no longer have that installed, but I do still have the fonts, which when viewed with FontForge show a Copyright notice *(Element > Font Info > PS Names > Copyright)* of:

> (c) 1995, Star Division GmbH, Hamburg

I tried finding info about the license of the font, read up on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StarOffice#Components), searched for license info on font websites, but no luck. Basically, I want to know if I can use these fonts commercially. By "commercially" I mean: use the fonts to create images where the images are for commercial use, (as opposed to selling software with the font, or selling the fonts themselves).

Some of the fonts that fall under this group are:

> Americano, Andorra, Arcus, Armada, ArtA, ArtB, ArtC, ArtD, ArtE, Artefakt, Avance, Aventure, Bahama, Baikal, Banberry, Baroness, Bavaria, Beda, Benelux, Brequet, CadillacCaps, Camarco, Cephyr, Chelsea, Cleo, Domo, EnriqueCaps, Erato, Eriva, Farny, Frantic, Gamins, Gero, Goncourt, Helmet, Houdon, Kiddy, Korinth, LarmaCaps, Murnau, Nuance, Opera, Pakira, Proto, Rocco, Sega, Slim, Solo, Styx, Symco, Timida, Timmons, Tintin, Uncopro, Uncorpo, Undine, Usage, Veltina, Wassily, Zazie

Comment: It says copyright 1995, and since in most countries (c) is 50 or 70 years, I don't think so...

Comment: Licenses don't change. If you got them under a "personal use only" license.. that's what they are.. personal use **only**.

Comment: @PieBie, the copyright is different to the license. License means what I can do with it, and copyright who owns the rights to it.

Comment: @Scott, Actually licenses do change, as can be seen with the licensing of Star/Sun Office itself. Since the licensing for Sun Office changed when it became OpenOffice (or even from 5.1 to 5.2), I am unsure what happened with the licensing of the fonts, or what was the original licensing in the first place. (Fonts can be distributed under different license to the office suite itself).

Comment: Well that's a point of argument. The license for SunOffice never changed. There may be a separate, new, license for Open Office, but the original license hasn't changed. Just like My license for Adobe Photoshop CS6 is still in tact and valid, even though I have a *separate* license for Photoshop CC2015.

Comment: @Scott Yes, but you can still change the license for software. Like how Netscape decided to release the code for their browser, thereby changing the license for it. In any case, my question is about the fonts included, which don't necessarily have the same license (and the fact that I am not using the Sun Office 5.2 software anymore).

Comment: Actually, on a hunch, I went and tried to see if I had originally installed it from a sampler CD or something, and actually found the original install CD, which is for SunOffice 5.1 (not 5.2). So, no matter what, it seems I do have the right to use the fonts, since I have the original (legal) software installer with me. I am still curious to know the answer to the question, so I won't close it.

Comment: It still seems messy. You have the right to use the fonts in the **original** software. But I'm not sure you can extend that right to use them in other software. That said, it would be hard to actually prove in what software a certain image was made...

Comment: Actually, it wouldn't make sense to only allow the fonts to be used in *one* software alone, since you have to install it system wide. Fonts, after all, _are_ software, so in fact you are installing the software on your system. Basically, fonts are part of the software that you can install, so whether you use all the other software it came with or not, you can install the font and "run" that on its own.

Comment: More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29172751/2758435